# Best practice table scheme for active and non active field

Tags: cakephp, dry

i have simple table
Posts
id
title
content

what is the best practice to handle with non active post
1- use the temp_posts table to move non-active posts to this table
2- just set flag for post's active field

my own prefer is to use 1 solution,
cause you would not use condtion (active = 1) everytime i use find command

so what you can offer to escape of using condition (active = 1) everytime

Comment: Removed the scheme tag since this obviously has nothing to do with the Scheme programming language.

Answer (score 3):

It'd go with #2. You have the overhead of a completely separate Model and `find()` code with #1. If you didn't want to set t`condition = array('active' => 1)` everytime, default it in the Post Model by using `beforeFind()`. Although the latter may not work in all cases when finding on multiple models.

Comment: yes you right about #1 and beforeFind(), but it useless when you list all non-active post in admin pane. so is there any other DRY solutions

Comment: but i wouldnt use hardcoded 0 and 1 (not a good coding practice) @see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will make a lot of difference if the active field is numeric type. It will make many other operations easy. So I will go for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a best practice for this case, both solutions have their advantages and disadvantages, see Jason's answer.

Personally, I tend for #1, because on a conceptual level you probably have `Drafts` and `Posts`, and not `Posts` which are either active or inactive. It's a subtle difference, but in the first case the two models can have different attributes. For example, a `Post` will probably have a `PublicationDate`, whereas such an attribute doesn't make sense for a `Draft`. You can't model this by only using a `Post` model.